# What does the equals one mean - ISNULL (something, 1) = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code.

```
.....
.....
WHERE 0 = 0 
AND Isnull(something, 1) = 1
....
....
```

I know that isnull function looks at something and if it is a null replace it with 1. But what does the **=1** stand for exactly, what does it mean ?

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server and the code is Coldfusion.

Comment: @SalmanA Why wouldn't it? `WHERE 0=0` is as true as `WHERE 1=1`. If it were `WHERE null=null` then that wouldn't be true since null can't equal anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will replace the value of something (column name For a row) if it is null with 1 and then check if the output is one. basically, it is checking if the value is null.

Comment: It's not really checking if the value is null. It's saying that even if `something` is null, then still return that row.

Answer (score 8):

Your query `Isnull(something, 1) = 1` is saying to return `something` which has only `null` value with `1`.

I would re-write it as to make it *Sargable*  :

```
WHERE (something IS NULL OR something = 1)
```

Comment: Good point about removing ISNULL to make it [sargable](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE something IS NULL or something  = 1;
```

because `0=0` is always `true`.

Comment: This is a more explicit way of writing the logic, in my opinion.

Comment: it is and I don't think that I would prefer `Isnull(something, 1) = 1` although the latter seems more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The core of it is that if the value (something) that is null-checked is null or exactly 1 then the expression evaluates as true.

If something equals null then the result of ISNULL(p1, p2) evaluates to the value of p2.
If something equals anything other than null then it evaluates to the value of p1.
Then the expression evaluates against the result of ISNULL

```
p1     p2  ISNULL-result  expression  result
null   1   1              = 1         true
1      1   1              = 1         true
2      1   2              = 1         false
1      1   1              = 2         false
null   2   2              = 2         true
```